# How to display Android Dialog and keyboard at the same time

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to display a Dialog with an EditText field, pre-populate the EditText with a default value, select all in the EditText, give the focus to the EditText, and automatically pop open the keyboard.

However as soon as I show the Dialog, the keyboard retracts. If I display the Dialog first, the keyboard won't display.

I am displaying the keyboard with

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(getView(), 0);
```

What to do?

Comment: from the dialog guide: You can do this by setting the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM window flag (assuming your Dialog takes input focus, as it the default) with the following code:

 `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM); `, you can try this, i dont know it can fix your problem or not.

Comment: After displaying the Dialog, try setting the focus to that textbox which will automatically display the keyboard.

Comment: That worked! Thanks - but why didn't you post this as an answer, so that I could check you up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try With this..write on Your Dialog setOnShowListener method.like this before your alert dialog.show() method...

```
Dialogname.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
        }
    });
```

i tried with this..it's worked for me.